# paintComponent isn't being called, can't get image variables to work

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, japplet

So I know I suck at programming, but if anyone could give me some code help I would appreciate it, I don't know why I am getting this error

cannot find symbol

```
  g.drawImage(movPic2, 35, 515, 200, 200,this);                 ^
  symbol:   variable movPic2
  location: class MovieDis
```

if any1 could give me a code snippet example i have trouble understanding in just words.
tired of this program and just wanting to get done with it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent.*;

public class Movie extends JApplet {

    private String movName1;
    private String director1;
    private int yearMade1;
    private Image movPic1;
    private String movName2;
    private String director2;
    private int yearMade2;
    private Image movPic2;
    private String movName3;
    private String director3;
    private int yearMade3;
    private Image movPic3;
    private String movName4;
    private String director4;
    private int yearMade4;
    private Image movPic4;

    public void init() {
        MovieDis goo = new MovieDis(movPic1, movPic2, movPic3, movPic4);
        goo.setBounds(0, 0, 750, 500);
        add(goo);
    }
}

class MovieDis extends JComponent {

    private String movName1;
    private String director1;
    private int yearMade1;
    private Image movPic1;
    private String movName2;
    private String director2;
    private int yearMade2;
    private Image movPic2;
    private String movName3;
    private String director3;
    private int yearMade3;
    private Image movPic3;
    private String movName4;
    private String director4;
    private int yearMade4;
    private Image movPic4;

    public MovieDis(Image movPic1, Image movPic2, Image movPic3, Image movPic4) {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        movPic1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("Shaw.jpg");
        movPic2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("dances.jpg");
        movPic3 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Inception.jpg");
        movPic4 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Cuckoo.jpg");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 750, 500);
        g.drawImage(movPic1, 35, 35, 200, 200, this);
        g.drawImage(movPic2, 35, 515, 200, 200, this);
        g.drawImage(movPic3, 265, 35, 200, 200, this);
        g.drawImage(movPic4, 35, 515, 200, 200, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variable `movPic1` (and 2-4) are not stored anywhere inside your `MovieDis` class.  That's why the `paintComponent()` method is complaining.  You need to add those to `MovieDis` and then assign them in your class constructor.

Comment: hey this worked. thank you, i am still having a problem creating the images though, it gets to g.fillRect(0,0,750,500); and it doesnt draw the images it seems, is it something wrong with how i stored them in MovieDis constructor?

Comment: could you edit your question and update it to contain your new code?  thanks.

Comment: @user1547182: that seems like a new question. Consider 1+ orzechowskid's answer (as I have done), accepting it, and asking a new question.

Comment: it requires 15 reputation.  also i re edited my code orzechowskid, i hope i didnt do anything code illegal or bad, but i basically restated the variables in the second class because i didnt really use them in first

Comment: I just answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910783/images-are-not-showing-up-in-paint-component :(