# images are not showing up in paint component

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, japplet

it gives me a black screen for setbackground, 
         but it doesnt seem to read the images or draw them, 
             some help would be appreciated, also if you could tell me the information
           pertaining to my code, i have trouble understanding general 
         r vague answers, thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent.*;

public class Movie extends JApplet {

    private String movName1;
    private String director1;
    private int yearMade1;
    private Image movPic1;
    private String movName2;
    private String director2;
    private int yearMade2;
    private Image movPic2;
    private String movName3;
    private String director3;
    private int yearMade3;
    private Image movPic3;
    private String movName4;
    private String director4;
    private int yearMade4;
    private Image movPic4;

    public void init() {
        MovieDis goo = new MovieDis(movPic1, movPic2, movPic3, movPic4);
        goo.setBounds(0, 0, 750, 500);
        add(goo);
    }
}

class MovieDis extends JComponent {

    private String movName1;
    private String director1;
    private int yearMade1;
    private Image movPic1;
    private String movName2;
    private String director2;
    private int yearMade2;
    private Image movPic2;
    private String movName3;
    private String director3;
    private int yearMade3;
    private Image movPic3;
    private String movName4;
    private String director4;
    private int yearMade4;
    private Image movPic4;

    public MovieDis(Image movPic1, Image movPic2, Image movPic3, Image movPic4) {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        movPic1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("Shaw.jpg");
        movPic2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("dances.jpg");
        movPic3 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Inception.jpg");
        movPic4 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Cuckoo.jpg");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 750, 500);
        g.drawImage(movPic1, 35, 35, 200, 200, this);
        g.drawImage(movPic2, 35, 515, 200, 200, this);
        g.drawImage(movPic3, 265, 35, 200, 200, this);
        g.drawImage(movPic4, 35, 515, 200, 200, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to absolutly have to use an `JApplet`? If you're just playing around testing ideas, much easier to use a `JFrame`

Comment: Why on earth is the code passing 4 null image references to a constructor that is supposed to populate them?  I have seen code that passes 4 images, and code that passes 4 strings that represent paths to images, but your logic baffles me.

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230), to know more about where to place your images, and how to use them in your code :-)

Comment: Please have a look at this [Project.zip](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/Project.zip), I had made to let you know the directory structure and how to access images. The above links though explain in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

From what i can see, most likely your images are null or empty. Seeing how this is applet code and you're not using proper URLs, the Toolkit will likely return a sentinel value (an image with width and height = -1) if it can't locate the images. Unfortunately, g.drawImage will not throw an exception in this case. Please check that your images are loaded correctly.

Comment: how do i do this? i have 4 pictures in my classes folder

Comment: By using logging, or if you don't know how to do that by simply adding something like "g.setColor(Color.RED); g.drawString(movPic1.getWidth(null)+"/"+movPic1.getWidth(null),30,30);" to your paint method. The latter should render the size of movPic1 as red text on your component. If it is "-1/-1", your problem is the image loading.

Comment: i dont understand this at all sorry, all i am getting is  a blackscreen on the applett

Comment: If the images are embedded (compiled into the Jar) you need to cell `getClass().getResource("/...")`, which will return a URL to the image

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reason this might not work, the most obvious are

- You don't have permission to read the images (either of the file system or the URL)
- The URL reference is wrong (because the location of the files are not where you think they are)

Depending on where the files are stored, you have two choices.

If the files are stored on the server, along with the Jar.  You will need to know the document base reference.

So in your `init` method, you'll need add

```
URL base = getDocumentBase();
System.out.println("base = " + base); // testing only
movPic1 = getImage(base, "issue169.jpg");
movPic2 = getImage(base, "issue194.jpg");
movPic3 = getImage(base, "issue248.jpg");
movPic4 = getImage(base, "issue78.jpg");
```

This assumes that the images reside in the same directory on the server as the HTML file.  You can use relative paths as needed.

If the files are stored/bundled in the `Jar` (this is probably the preferred way for static images), you need to use the `classloader` to find them

```
try {
    movPic1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/testapplet/issue169.jpg"));
    movPic2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/testapplet/issue194.jpg"));
    movPic3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/testapplet/issue248.jpg"));
    movPic4 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/testapplet/issue78.jpg"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used this method but did run into a small problem while testing.  Because my files handed been bundled (yet), the applet viewer was trying to load them as a `File` reference which it didn't have permission to do - the applet view allows you to set it as unrestricted.

This eventually resulted in

[image]

PS- I set the applets layout manager to `BorderLayout` rather then using absolute positioning.